# Decompose a string variable into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

In some dataframe I'm currently working on, I have a column ('behavior') in which every entry is a string that describes missing tuition payments of students through time:

Every two spaces in the string correspond to period of time.
For example, If we have the string

`"01 V V"`

that means that the student, during the three periods of monitoring its payments, paid the first two on time but skipped the last one.

The most recent payment corresponds to the first two elements of the string (including spaces), the next two spaces correspond to the second, and so on

Here's an example of the first three entries of the data frame

```
pd.DataFrame({'subject':['S1', 'S2', 'S3'], 
              'behavior': [' V V V010101--0101', ' V V----01', '070707 V V--']})

  subject            behavior
0      S1   V V V010101--0101
1      S2           V V----01
2      S3        070707 V V--
```

What I need to do is decompose the strings into several columns, each one corresponding to a payment. For this example, this would imply creating 9 additional columns (payment 1, payment 2, and so on) since the behavior column's longest string contains information regarding 9 payments.

I've been trying to solve this but I can't seem to find the solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in 2 steps, first by making it a list (splitting by every 2 characters)

Then, you can break that out into columns if that's what you want.

```
def splitme(s, n):
    aslist = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
    return aslist
    
# new column is a list of every n=2 characters
df['as_list'] = df['behavior'].apply(lambda x: splitme(str(x), 2))

# now break into columns
pd.DataFrame(df["as_list"].to_list())
```